# How do you make a potion effect fall over an area in 1.12.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For example, I want to create a game that is similar to the experimental sky wars mode slime on the Hypixel server. In the game it allows people to not only jump high but double jump extremely high.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: it is unclear what your question is, do you want a lingering jump effect, or a double jump feature, or both?

Answer (score 1):

High jump can be achieved with this command:

```
/effect @a jump_boost 10 1000000
```

That gives every player jump boost 10 for a lot of seconds. If you also want to include every future player, put it into a command block on a clock.

If you can double jump, then that's a more complicated command block system, it's not a potion effect. If you still want to try it, search on YouTube for SethBling's "double jump in Minecraft" video.